# get data from a row with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Sorry for my question but this is first time I came here and also I did some search but never found any answer for my solution.

I'm new with ajax and try to figure out my question here.

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
<thead>
<th></th>
<th></th>
</thead>

<tbody>

<tr>
<td>aaa</td><td>bbb</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>aaa</td><td>bbb</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Then I need a solution to when I click on a row, it will get text content from td tag and filled to another DIV with label and input tag.

How can I do this ? All of your help are appreciated.

Comment: Very broad question - many people use the jQuery javascript library for this sort of thing.  It makes it easy to handle the click events on the rows as well as select data from particular cells.  Finally, it gives you easy methods to make your ajax calls to get the remote data.  So, maybe take a look at some jquery examples and come back with more specific questions.

Comment: Is my question still not clear ? All I need is click in a row and get value from that row, first <td> and second <td> and set those values to another tag in another div.

Comment: Well, as a start - the following would be a jquery row click handler $('#tableid').on('click', 'tr', function() {
   var row = $(this).find('td:first').text();
   alert('You clicked ' + row);
}); that assumes your table has an id="tableid" and would read the value of the first td.

Comment: sorry - code formatting not possible in comments, I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery - the following javascript would add a row click handler and popup the value from the first cell in the row:

```
$('#tableId').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var row = $(this).find('td:first').text();
    alert('You clicked ' + row);
});
```

The selector is using the id from the table element, so you need to give your table element a table id.  Once you have that working, instead of the alert, you can just update another div like this:

```
$("#idOfYourDiv).text(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the click event on document ready like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tr").click(onRowClick);
});
```

Then, in the onRowClick function, find td elements of a row (it will be $(this)) and traverse through them using the each method:

```
function onRowClick(evt) {
    $(this).find("td").each(function () {
        console.log($(this).html());
    });            
}
```

In my sample, I write cell values to Console. You can write them where you need.